# How to produce references style in bibtex with author's laste name first and then the abbreviation afterwards, and "pp" before the page numbers

Tags: bibtex

This paper: [The power of two-sided platforms to disseminate resistant innovations](https://www.emerald.com/insight/content/doi/10.1108/MD-06-2019-0727/full/html?_ga=2.10008821.1371787977.1649797058-365402973.1649797058) shows a style of references which I do not know. For example:

> Tucker, C. and Zhang, J. (2010), “*Growing two-sided networks by advertising the user base: a field experiment*”, Marketing Science, Vol. 29 No. 5, pp. 805-814, doi: 10.1287/mksc.1100.0560.

I'm using LaTeX and the file format "bibtex" to describe and process my list of references in such a format. I'm using the options from the package "natbib". How can I reproduce a similar style for the references?

Comment: Rather than look around for an existing bib style that matches all of your formatting requirements, you may be better off running the `makebst` utility -- part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib) package -- to create a bespoke bib style from scratch.

Comment: @Mico Thank you. I do not know how to work with makebst. Could you provide an example please?

Comment: Did you follow the link I provided? Did you search this site for the string `makebst`? Basically, you need open a command window and type `latex makebst` to launch the utility. You'll be asked a lot of multiple choice questions (with the defeault or fallback answer marked with `*`). At the end of the process, you'll be asked if you want to create a bst file (aka bibliography style file) that incorporates your answer choices. If  you type `y` ("yes"), you'll get the bespoke bst file.